# How can I change the background and foreground colors in the overleaf GUI?

Tags: overleaf

This is not really a Tex/LaTeX question but I would like to change the background and foreground colors in the overleaf graphical interface for a better visual comfort when using it. I would like to have it for all panes, not just the PDF one (I guess that this can be done easily with appropriate LaTeX commands for the PDF part). Is there a simple way to do it? If not, how can I ask for the feature to be integrated in next releases?

Note: I find this [dark mode add-on for firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/overleaf-dark-mode/) but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You are right that this is not really on-topic here, you would have to ask OverLeaf support for guidance, if you go `Help` and then `Contact us` you can ask them this question

Answer (score 2):

You could try setting the theme of the editor in the menu (top left):

[image: editor theme]

Comment: Thanks. That works. I was looking for this but was unable to find it alone in the menu. It works for the input pane only but the following does it for the PDF pane:   \pagecolor[rgb]{0,0,0} %black
\color[rgb]{0.9,0.9,0.9} %light grey